# How to split Diazo rules the sane way?

Tags: xslt, plone, diazo

I faced this problem more than once so far and now I'd like to find
a perfect solution:

when you have a very complex diazo theme, sooner or
later you will end up splitting the rules into subsets and move them in
separate files.

My habit is to keep them separated based on the template
to which they have to be applied. Now, what's the better solution for
selecting which of them should be applied?

By now I've found these 2
solutions:

1. you can have a list of "rules" with conditions that identify the
   template and then import the correct external xml. There are 2 cons
   here, you have to hope that all the conditions are mutually
   exclusive, and the "otherwise" option, which is basically another
   "rules" with all the previous conditions inside a `not()`, grows
   insanely huge
2. you can use a `xsl:choose`, but it seems that this option doesn't
   work perfectly as the `xsl:otherwise` option is not always applied
   and I'm not sure that the construct ends on the first verified
   `xsl:when`

Am I missing something? do you have other options or you can select
which of these two is the best?

Answer (score 1):

So this is a half answer. I'm not a diazo expert but Thijs-Code is and he's got a lot of examples of splitting out rule-sets and reusing different parts of diazo themes that you might want to take a look at.

His github acct:

```
https://github.com/TH-code
```

Example theme:

```
https://github.com/TH-code/diazotheme.purecss/blob/master/diazotheme/purecss/theme/rules.xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Nathan,though my use case is a little different. Thijs splits the page into chunks, while I need to include many entirely different rules sets depending on the path and/or other variables. I'm going to improve my question in order to provide more details. Thank you again.